# Whats the difference between Double.valueOf(String s) and Double.ParseDouble(String s)?

Tags: java

As I understand the doc, ParseDouble function made something like :

```
 Double parseDouble(String s) throws ... {       
      return new Double(Double.valueOf(s));
 }
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The logic is the same, but the return value of Double.valueOf() return a heap allocated Double object, where as parseDouble returns a primitive double.  Your code example is not quite correct.  The java source reads:

```
public static double parseDouble(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(s).doubleValue();
}

public static Double valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return new Double(FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(s).doubleValue());
}
```

Comment: thx, so the cost is less for parseDouble(String s) when you just need the value,  and not all methods attached...

Answer (score 2):

Depends on whether you want a double or a Double. Although with autoboxing, it doesn't really matter. If you are doing something very intensive then you want to avoid using doubles in places where Doubles are needed in order to avoid the autoboxing overhead. But, it would need to be very, very, very, intensive before it actually makes any difference.

I would still, however, advocate using the proper one according to the desired result.

Comment: yes. In fact I just need the value, so I will use double primitive.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that autoboxing creates any more overhead than calling `Double.valueOf(somePrimitiveDouble)` explicitly?  I would almost guarantee it would have no extra overhead.  The time when you would want to avoid it is in the other direction: when you call `valueOf` which gives you a Double, and you only need a primitive.  That would be pointless overhead.

Answer (score 1):

`parseDouble` returns a `double value`, valueOf returns a new `object` of type `Double`.

Comment: I don't think there's anything that says it has to be a *new* Double.

Answer (score 1):

Simple,

```
public static double parseDouble(String s) throws NumberFormatException
```

returns a java primitive `double`, while

```
public static Double valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException
```

returns a *wrapped* double value in a `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

valueOf returns a double, parseDouble returns a Double. Use whichever suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 6 the reverse is true:

```
Double valueOf(String s) throws ... {       
      return new Double(Double.parseDouble(s));
}
```