# String to double locale error

Tags: android, string, double

In my app, I use text boxes for entering decimal number values.

From there, I use

```
Double.valueOf();
```

to get the value as a double. This works fine, except some users with different locales are getting errors.

How do I make sure this doesn't happen? Also, should I be using Double.ParseDouble() or Double.valueOf()?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know if this is your case, but note that different locales  have different decimal points, e.g. "," in stead of ".". For ParseDouble() vs valueOf() see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3708931/whats-the-difference-between-double-valueofstring-s-and-double-parsedoublestri

Comment: Yes, I think that's the problem, I'm just not sure the best way to deal with it... Thanks for the link, it looks like I should probably be using parseDouble instead of valueOf.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following Java methods to parse a double that has been
typed by the user and stored in string `s`.

However, I know the locale the user is using.  If you do not
know then it is difficult to be certain how to parse the number
because a value such as "100.000" means different things
in different locales.

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = DecimalFormat.getInstance(locale);
numberFormat.setGroupingUsed(false);
ParsePosition parsePosition = new ParsePosition(0);
Number n = numberFormat.parse(s, parsePosition);
if (n == null || parsePosition.getErrorIndex() >= 0 || parsePosition.getIndex() < s.length())
{
  /* not a valid number */
}
```

Comment: There's also `DecimalFormat.getInstance()` which uses the default locale. That should be fine on Android.